# E11000 duplicate key error collection: ad-network.users index: username_1 dup key: { : null }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to register with different phone numbers and emails , but 1st user registration successfull after that getting Error like:

my user schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({

name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
},
phone: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
},
type: {
    type: String,
},
admin_rights: {
    type: String
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
```

});

is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have a index for username_1 field but you try to assing null for this filed. So mongo returns dup key: { : null } error. Drop index on this field and create again with this option { sparse: true }

Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the indexed field, even if the index field contains a null value.

Answer (score 0):

I just drop my collection using `db.collectionName.drop()` **It worked for me but it is not the suitable way to do this. i was working with local and considering the data which is stored in my collection is not useful so i drop.**